# then() method is executing before the data is actually returned in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please see the code below:

```
class WhiteBoard extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.userService = new UserService();
    this.state = {user: []};
}

userLogin = (user) => {
    console.log("inside whiteborad user login");

    let loginuser = {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
    };
    console.log(loginuser);

    this.userService.getLoggedInUser(loginuser)
        .then( data => {
            console.log("adsad"+mydata);
            this.setState({user: mydata})
        });

    console.log(this.state.user)
}
```

And UserService is below:

```
class UserService {

async getLoggedInUser(user){
    console.log("inside user service");
    console.log(user);
    const USER_API_URL = API_URL + "/api/login";
    fetch(USER_API_URL, {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        method : "POST",
        body : JSON.stringify(user)
    }).then(response => response.clone().json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}
}

export default UserService;
```

I am getting the following output in console:

```
inside whiteborad user login
WhiteBoard.js:29 {username: "bird", password: "bird"}
UserService.js:6 inside user service
UserService.js:7 {username: "bird", password: "bird"}
WhiteBoard.js:37 []
WhiteBoard.js:33 adsadundefined
UserService.js:16 {id: 100, username: "bird", password: "bird", firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Kathie", …}
```

The problem is, I am getting undefined data in the then method called in userService.getLoggedInUser().then() part. Because of this, setState is not working and returning null. Data is coming perfectly fine in userService method. But, in userLogin method, when I called userService, it's then method is not waiting to get the response from the userService function. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to return the result of calling `fetch`; `getLoggedInUser()` itself returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you employ a promise, but don't `return` it so the caller has no connection to it and instead your `then` chains on to the `async` function's default promise. The normal fix here would be to `return fetch(...)` but you can take another approach since you're using `async` functions.

To fix it take advantage of `async` and use `await`:

```
class UserService {
  async getLoggedInUser(user){
    console.log("inside user service");
    console.log(user);
    const USER_API_URL = API_URL + "/api/login";

    let response = await fetch(USER_API_URL, {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        method : "POST",
        body : JSON.stringify(user)
    });

    let data = await response.clone().json();

    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now it's properly sequenced.

When using promises with `then` chaining one of the most common problems is dropping the ball and forgetting to explicitly `return` the promise which *needs* to be waited on before proceeding.

Comment: Would `return fetch(USER_API_URL, {...` work? (after dropping `async` in the function declaration)

Comment: Dropping the `async` isn't necessary, but the `return` is if you're not going to `await`. You need to carry that ball forward somehow. `async` functions are allowed to return promises, in which case they chain properly.

Comment: Thanks, it actually solved the issue. I had no idea this was the problem. cheers!